# Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

Tags: highcharts, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

[image: Error Code while trying to run composer require --prefer-dist miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget "dev-master"]

I have deleted the composer folder inside AppData and re-installed it globally but still having the same error. I have also tried to run composer.phar require --no-plugins miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget "dev-master" yet I still get the same error as show on the attached file. I need help on how to get pass this.

Comment: [yii2-highcharts-widget](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts) is not the same as Highcharts and your problem doesn't look like an issue with Highcharts, but if you will have any problems with Highcharts, please specify them.

Comment: Thanks. Already fixed the high chart issue. I simply downloading the highchart folder and included it as a file as oppose to installing using composer.